# Truncate the table using hibernate criteria API

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I wanted to delete all the records in a table using hibernate criteria, like

```
Criteria criteria = <session>.createCriteria("table name here");
criteria.(<.....>);
```

I am getting lots of help as below

```
session.createSQLQuery("truncate table MyTable").executeUpdate();
```

Is there any way to truncate using Criteria class, or any other class i can use Please let me know

Comment: No, there's no way. Even HQL doesn't support truncating. Criteria supports select only.

Comment: Truncate always removes all rows from a table. I don't know of any DBMS that supports truncate with a where clause. The whole purpose of truncate is to get rid of *all* rows **fast**.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done in one line with simple native query:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("TRUNCATE my_schema.my_table").executeUpdate();
```